# Destructuring a function in a list

Tags: clojure, destructuring

I have the following two test cases in Clojure, one destructuring a vector, and one destructuring a list:

```
user=>  ((fn [[a op b]] (op a b)) [1 + 2])
3
user=>  ((fn [[a op b]] (op a b)) '(1 + 2))
2
```

Why is the symbol + evaluated in the first test case but not the second?  Is the quote recursive, so in the second test case `op` is really `'op`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the single quote `'` (equivalent of the function `quote`) will return a list of symbols, suppressing evaluation. However, since symbols cannot start with a number, the `PersistentList` `'(1 + 2)` will contain a `java.lang.Long`, a `clojure.lang.Symbol`, and a `java.lang.Long`.

When you invoke the function given by the `Symbol` `+` (which is possible because `Symbol` extends `AFn` which itself implements `IFn`, [and overrides the `invoke` function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L125)), this gets executed:

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object notFound) {
    return RT.get(obj, this, notFound);
}
```

Since you executed `(op a b)`, or `('+ 1 2)`, `obj` is `1`, `notFound` is `2`, and `this` is the `Symbol` `+` in the call to `clojure.lang.RT`'s `get` method, which [looks like this](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L775):

```
static public Object get(Object coll, Object key, Object notFound){
    if(coll instanceof ILookup)
        return ((ILookup) coll).valAt(key, notFound);
    return getFrom(coll, key, notFound);
}
```

Again, `coll` is the `Long` 1, key is the `Symbol` `+`, and notFound is the `Long` 2.

So when a function is called, it's being looked up in a collection.  Since `1` is not a collection, the value `notFound`, or `2`, is being returned.

As a visual of a `('+ 5 10)` example, in a debugger:

[image: Symbol in debugger]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm not sure that `notFound` is what's getting returned though, the return value seems to be the third value in the collection.  For instance, `((fn [[a op b]] (op a b)) '(2 + 5))` returns `5` in my repl.  Do you know why that might be the case?

Comment: @GLee As mentioned, you are invoking a Symbol as a function, and when this is done, the first arg is expected to be a map containing what the symbol refers to. The first argument is 2, which is not a map, and so 5 is returned as the "not found" value.  Type this: `(('+ {'- /} *) 8 9)` in your REPL. This says: invoke '+, and look up its symbol. The map contains a mapping from the symbol `'-` to the `/` function only. Since `'+` is not found, the default `*` is returned, which is then applied to 8 and 9 for a value of 72. So `('+ 2 5)` tries to look up `'+`, can't find it, and returns 5.

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood. That makes sense now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First we can simply see if the forms are destructured the expected way or not with a simple println:

```
(def fn1 
(fn [[a op b]] 
 (println "a>" a) 
 (println "b>" b) 
 (println "op>" op) 
 (op a b)))


 (fn1 [1 + 2])
 ; a> 1
 ; b> 2
 ; op> #object[clojure.core$_PLUS_ 0x5b95b23d clojure.core$_PLUS_@5b95b23d]

 (fn1 '(1 + 2))
 ; a> 1
 ; b> 2
 ; op> +
```

So in the first case, the parenthesis evaluates the clojure.core's function PLUS, which gives the expected (+ 1 2) => 3.

<del>In the second case, you can picture the sequence of forms to be evaluated as an implicit sequence, so call eval on it will give:

      (eval ('+ 1 2))
      ; 2

Which is simply the result of eval-ing each form in the sequence, and so only returns the last value, here 2.

You can think of it as:

     (do 
        '+ 
        1 
        2)</del>

As hinted in the comment, do is not call.

The '+ is a clojure.lang.Symbol which implements IFn. Thus when calling eval, it will call the java function invoke, with two parameters 1 and 2.

```
 (invoke 1 2) ; is called on +'
```

Looking at 2 parameters method of invoke for Symbol:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L129

We notice it will search for the symbol +' in the first parameter, which should be a map.

```
(def a {'+ 0})
(apply '+ [a 2])
; 0
```

When the item (here symbol) cannot be found, the invoke function returns the default value, the second parameter of the invoke function:

```
(def b { })
(apply '+ [b 2])
; symbol + is not found in b so returning 2
; 2
```

Comment: While there is some good information here, your last statement `(do '+ ...` is not equivalent to `(eval ('+ 1 2))` ... To see this, try `(eval ('+ 1 2 3 4))` and you will see that `Symbol`'s `invoke` function is indeed being called, and that the arity is incorrect, whereas you can pass any number of arguments to the `(do...` form and the last one will always be returned.  As such, your answer does not really address why the number `2` is being returned.

Comment: Yes, it does appear that the `do` example is not equivalent to the `eval` example.  However, the `do` example seems to match what I'm seeing in the repl.  The part I still don't understand is, why is list evaluated implicitly?  Intuitively, I'd expect the function to just return the list '('+ 1 2).

Comment: @GLee The function will return what you are telling it to: `(op a b)`.  In the first case, your function is taking a vector, which is destructured into 3 things: a Long, a Function, and a Long. In your repl type: `(type +)` to confirm that `+` is a function.  This function is defined (here)[https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L976]. In the second case, your function takes a list, which is destructured into 3 things: a Long, a Symbol, and a Long. Look at my answer and read what happens when you try to invoke a Symbol with 2 args--Symbol.java line 129.